# Add items to set inside a function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, set

I would like to better understand how we can add an item to a set as part of a function call, for example.

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        
        result = []
        self.backtrack(nums, result, [], set()) 
        return result
    
    def backtrack(self, nums, result, perm, visited):
        
        if len(perm) == len(nums):
            result.append(perm)
        
        for num in nums:
            if num not in visited:
                visited.add(num)
                self.backtrack(nums, result, perm+[num], visited)
                visited.remove(num)
```

Looking at the for loop we can see that num is added to the array inside the backtrack function call, similarly if perm was a string then the code would look like,

```
backtrack(num, result, perm + str(num), visited)
```

This seems to suggest to me that when we want to add an item inside a function call their type must match, which is why adding num without the list cast would fail when perm is a list.

```
backtrack(num, result, perm + num, visited) # Fails
```

So then with that, is it possible to do the same for a set ? I tried

```
backtrack(num, result, perm + [num], visited + set(num))
backtrack(num, result, perm + str(num), visite + (num))
```

but both failed, seeing as an array and a set are both objects it seems strange to me that only 1 supports adding like so.

Could someone shed some light please !

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding type annotations to everything so you can run a type checker makes the failures a lot easier to interpret, since `mypy` will tell you exactly what type is expected for each operation and how that doesn't match what you provided.  I annotated `backtrack` as follows:

```
def backtrack(
    nums: List[int],
    result: List[List[int]],
    perm: List[int],
    visited: Set[int]
) -> None:
```

Now if I try the lines of code in your question and run `mypy` I get useful error messages explaining why each is wrong (many of the failures are due to unrelated typos, e.g. using `num` instead of `nums` and `visite` instead of `visited`):

```
backtrack(num, result, perm + num, visited) # Fails
    error: Argument 1 to "backtrack" has incompatible type "int"; expected "List[int]"
    error: Unsupported operand types for + ("List[int]" and "int")
```

```
backtrack(num, result, perm + [num], visited + set(num))
    error: Argument 1 to "backtrack" has incompatible type "int"; expected "List[int]"
    error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("Set[int]")
    error: Argument 1 to "set" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Iterable[<nothing>]"
```

```
backtrack(num, result, perm + str(num), visite + (num))
    error: Argument 1 to "backtrack" has incompatible type "int"; expected "List[int]"
    error: Unsupported operand types for + ("List[int]" and "str")
    error: Name 'visite' is not defined
```

The set/list addition operators work the same way regardless of whether they happen as part of a function argument.  As the error message `Unsupported left operand type for + ("Set[int]")` indicates, you can't add (`+`) two sets.  Instead you union (`|`) them:

```
backtrack(nums, result, perm + [num], visited | set([num]))  # no errors!
```

Comment: Even though I like the content of this answer, it does not really focus on answering the question, does it?

Answer (score 3):

> This seems to suggest to me that when we want to add an item inside a function call their type must match, which is why adding num without the list cast would fail when perm is a list.

1. "Inside a function call" has **absolutely nothing to do with it**. Operators work the same way everywhere they are used.
2. For `+` to work, the types on either side of the + sign have to support the operation. That's all there is to it. You can define `+` for your own classes to add unlike types together. (You probably shouldn't.)
3. Casting is not a thing in Python. The `[]` is **creating** a list, that has one element: the existing value named `num`.

> So then with that, is it possible to do the same for a set ?

No. The `set` type does not support the operator at all. You can test this directly:

```
>>> help(set.__add__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'set' has no attribute '__add__'
```

This does allow *other* types to define `+` such that you can add a set *to* them; however, `list` explicitly disallows this, just as it's not allowed to "add" lists and tuples together (this decision is made because it's not clear what the result type should be).

> seeing as an array and a set are both objects

This *does not matter and is not interesting*. Yes, a list (`array` means something different in Python and is not built-in) is an object. So is a set. *So is a string*. So is a *function*. So is the `class Solution` itself, *as well as* instances of that class. In Python, we take "everything is an object" quite seriously.

> would like to better understand how we can add an item to a set

For this purpose, we have an explicit named method: `.add`. We can also use the operator `|` to combine two sets, as helpfully pointed out by @DavidWierichs (I need more caffeine). Combining two sets is conceptually a different operation - a *set union* rather than concatenation (you don't preserve the invariant that the combined `len` equals the sum of the original `len`s; and you don't preserve order, since conceptually there is no order to preserve in the first place) - so a different operator was chosen.

Comment: Great effort explaining the concepts behind this question! Note that the `set` operation equivalent to `+` on `list`s is `|` whereas `set.add()` corresponds to `list.append()`. This also shows that it would be *very, very* confusing to have the `+` operator defined on `set`s but have it do something different than `.add()`.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I blanked on that. I have edited the last paragraph accordingly.